# xml, xsl transformation with CDATA

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, transformation

I am new to xsl xml transformation. For now, I have an xml file that contains the following information:

```xml
<bio>
<published>Tue, 7 Oct 2008 14:47:26 +0000</published>
<summary><![CDATA[
   Dream Theater is an American <a
   href="http://www.last.fm/tag/progressive%20metal" class="bbcode_tag"
   rel="tag">progressive metal</a> band formed in 1985 under the name
   &quot;<a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Majesty"
   class="bbcode_artist">Majesty</a>&quot; by <a
   href="http://www.last.fm/music/John+Myung"
   class="bbcode_artist">John Myung</a>,
   <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/John+Petrucci"
   class="bbcode_artist">John Petrucci</a>
]]>
</summary>
</bio>
```

And my xsl file contains this:

```xml
<h3><xsl:value-of select="lfm/artist/bio/published"/></h3>
<p>
   <xsl:value-of select="lfm/artist/bio/summary" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</p>
<html>
   <body>
      <xsl:value-of select="lfm/artist/bio/content"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do now is to extract the tag-structured data out of the `<summary><[CDATA[]]></summary>` and show it in the browser as in this example:

```html
<a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/progressive%20metal" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">progressive metal</a>
<a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Majesty" class="bbcode_artist">Majesty</a>
<a href="http://www.last.fm/music/John+Myung" class="bbcode_artist">John Myung</a>
<a href="http://www.last.fm/music/John+Petrucci" class="bbcode_artist">John Petrucci</a>
```

For now when I open the xml page, it shows all the `CDATA` content, even with those html tags... I want to get those tags to do their job properly in html form.

sorry for the terrible description..hope you guys can get what i mean here...

Comment: -1 For the terrible description: you didn't really try hard to describe it better, did you? +1 For the question itself (if I did not misinterpret you) = 0. By the way, I didn't simplified the content of your original `xml` as there is already an answer referring to it. You could have simplified it so much just shortening urls, and removing irrelevant info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The CDATA is just (a part of) a text node and what seems like markup inside it is one-dimensional text (badly destroyed markup)** and this cannot be accomplished (in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0) without calling an extension function.

`<p><xsl:copy-of select="my:parse(lfm/artist/bio/summary)"></p>`

**In XSLT 3.0 there may be a new standard function [`parse-xml()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml) that does exactly this**.

**Update**:

**Here is a complete code example, assuming you are using `XslCompiledTransform` in .NET**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="summary/text()">
  <xsl:copy-of select="my:parse(.)/*/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <msxsl:script language="c#" implements-prefix="my">
  public XmlDocument parse(string text)
  {
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("&lt;t>"+text+"&lt;/t>");

    return doc;
  }
 </msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<bio>
 <published>Tue, 7 Oct 2008 14:47:26 +0000</published>
 <summary><![CDATA[Dream Theater is an American <a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/progressive%20metal" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">progressive metal</a> band formed in 1985 under the name &quot;<a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Majesty" class="bbcode_artist">Majesty</a>&quot; by <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/John+Myung" class="bbcode_artist">John Myung</a>, <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/John+Petrucci" class="bbcode_artist">John Petrucci</a>]]>
 </summary>
</bio>
```

**the wanted, correct result (the CDATA is replaced by the reconstituted markup) is produced**:

```
<bio>
  <published>Tue, 7 Oct 2008 14:47:26 +0000</published>
  <summary>
    <a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/progressive%20metal" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">progressive metal</a>
    <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Majesty" class="bbcode_artist">Majesty</a>
    <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/John+Myung" class="bbcode_artist">John Myung</a>
    <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/John+Petrucci" class="bbcode_artist">John Petrucci</a>
  </summary>
</bio>
```

Comment: actually, by the code you gave me... i still cannot get those html tags within <summary> to display on browser properly...any more suggestions? thx

Comment: @sefirosu: I guess you haven't coded the extension function. There are different rules of creating ext. functions, depending on the particular XSLT processor you are using. In case you let us know what XSLT processor/ OS you are using, people will be able to point to you the resources, describing how to write an extension function for that particular XSLT processor. It might be a good idea to ask this as a separate question. For example, if you're using .NET and XslCompiledTransform, read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject.aspx

Comment: @sefirosu: I updated my answer with complete code that can be used with the .NET XslCompiledTransform XSLT processor.

Comment: +1 For your magnificent interpretation skills. It took me quite a while to grasp what the OP wanted to do. Wish I could +1 again for your splendid answer as well ;-)