# Extract image from CDATA-xml rss file into xslt

Tags: image, xslt, cdata

I need show with xslt information about an xml RSS feed. 
The xml source is:

```
<description><![CDATA[<p>
<img style="margin: 10px; 
     float: left;" alt="Nuevo modelo general de negocio" 
     src="http://mysite.es/images/figure1.jpg" width="196" height="147" />
     La compañía apuesta por un marcado giro en el modelo]]>
</description>
```

I´m using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

But the rendering is not good because I need  show a resize image, with size, for example 70x70.

I´ve tried with this but its wrong:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace("description","images/","images/resized/images/")" 
   disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

The perfect solution for me would be to extract separated, both the src property and the text from the   tag.

Regards,
María

Comment: please see answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273065/xml-xsl-transformation-with-cdata

Comment: You can do this easily with XSLT 3.0 (XPath 3.0). Are you interested in an XSLT 3.0 solution? Or, for .NET XslCompiledTransform use the technique I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8273277/36305

Comment: Sorry, I´m new with xslt and I cant give a response for your question... I´m creating a webpart in Sharepoint Foundation 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your xml always is like your example then you should be able to use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="rss/channel"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="rss/channel">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:variable name="item_link" select="link"/>
    <xsl:variable name="item_title" select="substring-after(description, '/&gt;')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="item_image" select="substring-before(substring-after(description, 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
    <li>
      <a href="{$item_link}">
        <img alt="" src="{$item_image}" width="70" height="70" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$item_title"/>
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect Per, with your code I can read the src attibute without problems... Thank you